# Pressure on a piston

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure

**There are 2 syringes X and Y connected to each other horizontally. [image]**

If pressure in atmosphere (P) is 1x10<sup>5</sup> Nm<sup>-2</sup> and the pressure we should apply on X to have the velocity when liquid come out is 0.4ms<sup>-1</sup> is nP, what's the value of n?